# After copying bash directory, edit filenames in new directoy?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm currently working on a problem in bash shell to copy a directory to a new one, and that when you check that new directory it will have changed the names of the files it copied. Not sure how to word it exactly so I'll show what it is supposed to output:

```
-------$ ls -a myproject/
 ./ ../ file1 file2.c file3.txt .this_is_a_hidden_file
 -------$ bkup myproject mybackup
 -------$ ls -a mybackup
 ./ ../ file1-BACKUP file2-BACKUP.c file3-BACKUP.txt
```

So what happens is that my second parameter in the script `bkup` copies what is in the first parameter, then edits the names of the files of parameter #1 to add "-BACKUP" between the stem and the extension (eg. between `file2` and `.c` to make `file2-BACKUP.c`)

I have figured out how to copy the directories using `cp -a sourceDir./ destinationDir` but how would I edit the file names within `destinationDir`? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **rename** command to rename multiple files using regex, try below

```
# change directory to the destination folder
$ cd destinationDir

# rename all files 
# -n flag will only display how files will be renamed 
# once satisfied then remove the -n flag from below command and it will actually rename all files
$ rename -n -v 's/(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)/$1-BACKUP$2/' *
```

You can parameterize the command and include this in your script (bkup)
I am not in front of my Linux box .. so please test and let me know if you see any error.

Comment: It looks like it works from the output `file1 renamed as file1-BACKUP` but when I do `ls -a foo` the names are still the same. NEVERMIND I GET IT! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: could not understand your comment, command should rename file1 to file1-BACKUP, file1.c to file1-BACKUP.c , .this_is_hidden  to .this_is_hidden-BACKUP. Are you looking for something else or tell me scenario (with expected output) which is failing

Comment: This is great code and it's exactly what I'm looking for, however there is one condition I was wondering you could help me with. For .this_is_hidden could we have that not change?

Comment: Please check if wild card * select hidden files .. I guess not then it should be safe for hidden files and will not be changed.